Issue on sending CAN message using CAPL on CANalyzer
I am trying to emulate Checksum logic using CAPL. I have 8 byte of message. I want to sum first 7 bytes followed by Xor with 0xFF and store this value into 8th byte. So far things are working well. However, while running below code, values do update locally but not on the CAN message. I learned that there are some limitation while sending CAN message using CAPL on Canalyzer. Is there any solution to this problem?
on message X
{
  sum = 0;

  // Sum the first seven bytes of the message
  for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
  {
    sum += this.byte(i);
  }

  // XOR the sum with 0xFF to get the checksum
  checksum = sum ^ 0xFF;

  // Assign the checksum to the 7th byte (index 7) of the message
  this.byte(7) = checksum;

  // Print the calculated checksum for debugging purposes
  write("Calculated checksum: 0x%02X", checksum);
  
  // Transmit the modified message
  output(this);
}

Output(this) works only locally. It means it does not publish the CAN message while simulation is running. Can anyone help to solve this issue?

Where did you place the node that is executing this CAPL code?
